# meteor won't start becaus it is missing npm

Tags: meteor, meteorite

I just checked out my meteor project from [github](https://github.com/scaljeri/scrummie) and tried to run it, but now meteor doesn't want to start, telling me that `npm` is missing

I start my project as follows:

```
$> MONGO_URL='mongodb://localhost:27017/meteor' mrt
...
=> Started proxy.
=> Errors prevented startup:

While building the application:
error: no such package: 'npm'

=> Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.
```

In my project I use npm like

```
var fs = Npm.require('fs');
```

What I don't understand is why it doesn't work. I tried to install npm

```
$> mrt add npm
```

but that didn't fixed it. Any suggestions what the problem might be ?

Comment: After checking the code out, did you run `mrt install`?

Comment: I thought that when you run the code it installs the missing packages. I guess that this is only true for the stuff inside `packages.json`. Although `mrt install` didn't work, `mrt update` did!! Thnx a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

When you run the app with `meteor` command it only uses the packages installed locally in the `/packages` folder and built-in Meteor packages. To also install the atmosphere packages, you should run the app with `mrt` command. Alternatively, you could run `mrt install`, which downloads the atmosphere packages to the `/packages` directory, and thus allows you to start the app with `meteor`.